# Is it ok to adjust significance level according to number of comparisons in simple correlations?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

a referee asked me to "split" the significance level for the number of comparison, although i am not doing repeated comparisons but just spearman correlations between variables. I have set the significance level at p<0.05 but the referee is asking me to reduce it since the number of "correlations" is high. I wonder if it is ok to do so, or if I should reply to him stating that this is wrong (in which case i should need some reference if you have some). When is it necessary to adjust significance level for the number of comparisons? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

The referee is correct. The procedure he is referring to is called the Bonferroni correction. You should read about the problem of Multiple comparisons.